# Disallow duplicate columns for more than one other column value?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

The only answer I've come close to accepting is one involving the setting of a UNIQUE constraint on a column.

#### What I need to do is:

...in sql, to disallow duplicate entries between TWO columns.  So, say I have two columns, 'Parcel' and 'Year'. How would I go about disallowing a duplicate entry of Parcel = 1, Year = 1, and Parcel = 1, Year = 1?  I need to do this while still allowing duplicates in each respective column, just disallowing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a UNIQUE constraint the spans those two columns:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
add CONSTRAINT constraint_name UNIQUE (Parcel, Year);
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the unique constraint on the combination of the two columns. I normally do this kind of thing using a GUI rather than scripting it, so I can't give you any code to help out with that, though.